# Why do these two instructions vary in size?

Tags: c, pointers

Here are two instructions:

```
int p = 0;
int size_1 = (int*)(&p+1)-(int*)&p;
int size_2 = (char*)(&p+1)-(char*)&p;
```

I found that `size_1` is `1` and `size_2` is `4`. I was wondering why they vary this way

Comment: The distance between the start and end of an int is 1 int  , or 4 chars (on your system)

Comment: I do not understand the downvote on this question. Although it is a beginner-level question, I was interested in finding if there are any others answers other than the ones already given here.

Comment: Divide `size_2` by `sizeof(int)` and the result will be equal to `size_1`.

Answer (score 3):

This is basic *pointer arithmetic*. Oversimplifying a little bit, subtracting two `int*` produces the number of `int`s that fit between the two pointers (one), while subtracting two `char*` produces the number of `char`s that fit between the pointers (on your system, it happens to be four, because an `int` is four-byte wide).

Answer (score 2):

The root cause is that an `int` is 4 bytes on your system, while a `char` is 1 byte. The code `(&p+1)` will return a pointer to the memory address 4 bytes (the `sizeof(int)`) after `p`. Then when you assign to `size_1` you are asking for your answer in terms on `int` sizes, thus you get 1. For `size_2`, you are asking the difference between the address in `char` sizes, which gives 4.